# Publish Android library to Maven that depends on a local Android library project

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a library project, `libParent`, that includes another library project, `libChild`, as a dependency. If you look at the `build.gradle` dependencies section, you will see something like the following:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile project(':libChild')
}
```

Now, I want to publish `libParent` to maven as an `aar` file. Note that `libChild` has not been published, but I would like to include its sources/resources within `libParent`'s artificat. The maven publishing section of my `build.gradle` file looks like the following:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

Once I publish my module and include it as a dependency in my app, I get the following error:

```
Could not find 'libParent:libChild:unspecified'
     Searched in the following locations:
     https://oss.sonatype.org/content/respositories/snapshots/libParent/libChild/unspecified/libChild-unspecified.pom
```

I know that `libChild` is not getting baked into my published artifact, but how do I go about making sure that the sources/resources of `libChild` get included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't do it.**

If a library has a dependency, the pom file of the parent lib will contain this dependency.

You can't resolve this dependency including the sources/resources.
You have to publish also the child lib.

Comment: I was hoping for a sneaky way to do it, but I guess not. Thanks.